# What is the meaning and derivation of 'cowp'?

Tags: meaning, derivation

I just received an email from Scotland with the word 'cowp' in it. I had a vague recollection from my own Scottish background of such a word but could not remember what it meant.

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/43113?redirectedFrom=cowp#eid) has only this :

> Origin: A borrowing from early Scandinavian. Etymon: Norse kaup-a.
> Etymology: < Old Norse kaup-a to buy, bargain, barter, exchange, = Gothic kaupôn ...
> Scottish and northern dialect.
>
> - †1. transitive. To buy; figurative to abye, pay for, suffer for. Obsolete.
> - 2. to exchange, barter

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cowp) has this :

> cowp (plural cowps)
>
> (Scotland, Ireland, slang) **A filthy and disgusting place**.
> (dialect) A reversal of fortune; An unexpected misfortune.
>
> Verb : cowp (third-person singular simple present cowps, present participle cowping, simple past and past participle cowped) **To fall or tip over.**

As used in the email, the writer is referring to the Council Refuse Dump (they 'went to the cowp' and they clearly had something to dispose of) so it seems to me that 'cowp' as a verb means to tip something, either an accidental tip (Wiktionary-dialect) or a purposeful disposal into a cowp (the noun) being a place of refuse (Wiktionary - Scoland Ireland slang).

But none of this appears to agree with the OED.

Has anyone more background to this ?

Comment: What was the full sentence in the email?

Comment: @nnnnnn The email was personal so I simply stated in the question that it was clear that the native speaker of the language was referring to a Council Refuse Dump.

Comment: Dictionary of the Scottish Language (dsl.ac.uk) has a wide range of examples that goes well beyond the OED.

Comment: @Anton Do you have a direct link to the resource ?

Comment: Can't you provide an equivalent sentence with personal information removed? It would be nice to see the word properly in context given your explanation for the use in the email includes it as a possible verb *or* noun, which would make it an odd sentence.

Comment: @Anton The DSL.ac.uk has the same as above (OED/Wiktionary) both trading and tipping. I'm not sure what that tells me.

Comment: @nnnnnn The person says they went to the cowp, using it as a noun and the context made it clear they were disposing of something.

Comment: See https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/coup_n1

Comment: @Anton That is an excellent reference for this word and the source as a whole is very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verb and noun in the meaning of "to tip / a tip" seems to have developed from the French *coup/ couper* = to/a blow, to/a hit, etc. in the metaphorical sense:

"John's death came as a blow." > John's death was a blow > John's death was a great upset.

From this, the meaning "upset" took a further figurative step - "turning something (the current circumstances) over in an unpleasant way." Hence, **to/a tip.**

References from [A Dictionary of the Older Scottish Tongue (up to 1700)](https://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/dost/cowp_v_1)

> **Cowp, Coup, n.1 [e.m.E. coupe, ME. caupe a stroke, blow. Cf. Cowp v.1]**
>
> **An upset, overturning. — Stewart 4135.** Sum gat ane coup gart all hir tymmaris crak;
>
> Lynd. Sat. 2430. I man rin fast, in cace I get ane coup [B. cowp];
>
> **Cowp, Coup, v.1 Also: cowpe. *[Cf. ME. cowpe (rare) to strike.]**
>
> **1. tr. and intr. To turn up; to upset, overset, overturn. Knox II. 15.**
>
> Melvil Mem. 404. *What soeuer he be that reposes upon his gud seruice,
> is commonly cowped and wraked;*
>
> Adamson Muses Thr. 136. *The whirling stream will make our boat to coup;*

Which seems to have led to

> **2. To empty out by overturning.**
>
> 1653 Sir J. Hope Journal 155. *[I began] to inspect the earth about it & I thoght it lay all in little heapes as if it had been new coupped out of hurlebarrowes;*

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As an ulster scot, we would use coup as:
I couped a glass of water – I spilt a glass of water
I couped over – I fell over
I couped the rubbish in tae the bin – I tipped the rubbish into the bin
etc,

So maybe this is related to dumping rubbish?

Answer (score 2):

Here in Glasgow the cowp is the rubbish dump where rubbish is taken. Can be used as a verb too - I’ll cowp it. Fairly common word albeit informal on the whole.

> If your hoose is a clatty midden then tak yer guddle tae the cowp.

Ps I’m not a native but I’ve done my best!

Comment: Your quotation needs to be referenced, linked if possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you cowp something you make it fall or tip it over, usually accidentally, eg if you are at the dinner table and you carelessly hit the teacup and make it fall over, you have cowped the cup. My parents would say, “Watch what you’re doing or else you’ll cowp that cup!” Sometimes you would say “you’ll cowp it over!” It just means tip it over. We are a Scottish family from Central Scotland.

Also, if you want rid of household rubbish you would send it to the cowp, ie the rubbish tip or council rubbish tip.

If you left some tea in your cup you would take it to the sink and “tim it out”, ie empty the contents. Then, if the cup wasn’t too dirty and you wanted a fresh cup of tea you would “syne” (or “sine”) the cup under the tap before re-use. “syne or sine means “rinse”.

Another Scots word, similar to cowp or coup, is skail, skale, or scale. If for instance you are not careful when carrying a jug of water and you skail it, it means you have spilt the water or some of it. “I’m sorry. I skailt the water on the floor”.

Skail is probably an anglicised version of the Gaelic word “sgaoil”, to spread or to spill. Also, “‘tim” probably comes from the Old Scots or Irish word meaning “to empty”. Scotland’s king John Baliol in the 1290’s was nicknamed “Toom Tabard”, ie empty coat. A tabard was a coat of arms.

Answer (score 1):

I grew up in the Wigan area of Lancashire in the 1950s, when there were lots of broad dialect speakers, including my Grandad, a miner. I clearly remember 'cowp' being used to mean 'tip over'. In fact the definition fits the Northern Irish version I Googled, but not the Scottish one.

There is an Irish connection in the Wigan area, dating from the many Irish navvies who came in the 1700s when the Leeds -Liverpool Canal, which encircles Wigan, was constructed.

Check out many famous rugby players from Wigan: Byrne, Cassidy, O'Loughlin, Farrell and many more.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to German Kippe, a word that occurs in Müllkippe (some sort of rubbish dump) and Aschenkippe (an ash heap). As such, it is a filthy waste heap, pit or area.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Scottish:
Cowpt means **dump**, as in *the house was a cowpt*.

It can be used in: a cowpet yew, e.g., the yew was on its back.
I went to the council cowpt = I went to the council dump.

Comment: You need to substantiate what you report anecdotally by linking to references which support what you say.